# How do can create a remove method for a Java Card Class

Tags: java

How do can create a remove method for this Java Card Class?

Card class:

```
public class Card {
    
    private int value;
    private String rank;
    private String suit;
    
    public Card(String s, String r, int v) { suit=s;rank=r;value=v; }

    public int getValue() {return value;}
    public String getRank() {return rank;}
    public String getSuit() {return suit;}
}
```

---

The deck class with the remove method.
(Edit: I fixed the display method to not show the null cards and made the size return all cards discluding the null ones. The remove is also fixed. Thanks.)

```
public class Deck01 {
    
    private Card[] cards; //the deck
    private int size;     //size of deck and used for index for add()
    
    public Deck01(){
        cards = new Card[52];
        int size = 0;
    }
    
    //add a new card to cards[] at index=size
    public void add(String suit, String rank, int value){
        Card temp = new Card(suit,rank,value);
        cards[size] = temp;
        size++;
    }
    
    public void remove(String suit, String rank, int value){
        Card temp = new Card(suit,rank,value);
        
        //iterate through deck
        for (int s = 0;s<size;s++) {

            if ((temp.getValue())  == (-1)
                    &&temp.getRank()==(null)
                    &&temp.getSuit()==(null)) {
                s++;
            }
            if (temp.getValue()==(cards[s].getValue())
                    &&temp.getRank().equals(cards[s].getRank())
                    &&temp.getSuit().equals(cards[s].getSuit())) {
                cards[s]= new Card(null,null,-1);//remove card
            
            }
        }
        
    }
    
...
}
```

Comment: First thing to fix: `cards[size]=null;` should probably be `cards[s]=null;`. And add `return;` right after `size--;`

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: You have `import java.util.ArrayList;` but you never use it.  Consider using it instead of a fixed size array

Comment: Because you're removing a card in the middle of the array, using `size` to try and list it is pointless, unless you pack the array to remove `null`s from the middle (moving all the other other cards up), instead, use `cards.length` and simply skip over `null` values

Comment: Consider also, making a series of `static` constants of common cards, this way you can manage the `deck` using instances of `Card` and then rely on `equals` (and `hashcode`) instead

Comment: Yea, thanks (Stefan), now it works. I replaced cards[size]=null; with cards[s] null.

Comment: The display method is fixed so it skips over the null values. Thanks for bringing that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't change the size of an `array`,
I suggest using an `ArrayList`

```
private List<Card> deck = new ArrayList();

//you don't need class Deck anymore

deck.add(new Card("Clovers","Jack",11)); // to add
deck.remove(new Card("Clovers","Jack",11)); // to remove
System.out.println(deck.size()); // to print n. of cards

// to display
for (Card c: deck){
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Comment: I had to make it with a static array so instead I fixed it to replace the cards with "null".

Answer (score 0):

You can try using LinkedList for this purpose. Here is my code which works. You were doing mistake in your remove function. You should remove by index not size. Well here you don't even need size variable.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Deck01 {
    private List<Card> cards;

    public Deck01(){
        cards = new LinkedList<>();
    }
    public void add(String suit, String rank, int value){
        Card temp = new Card(suit,rank,value);
        cards.add(temp);
    }

    public void remove(String suit, String rank, int value){
        Card temp = new Card(suit,rank,value);
        for (int s = 0;s<cards.size();s++) {
            Card tempCard = cards.get(s);
            if (temp.getValue()==(tempCard.getValue())
                    &&temp.getRank().equals(tempCard.getRank())
                    &&temp.getSuit().equals(tempCard.getSuit())) {
                cards.remove(tempCard);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println(cards);
    }

    public int getSize(){return cards.size();}

    public boolean isEmpty(){ return cards.isEmpty(); }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Deck01 [cards=" + cards + ", size=" + cards.size() + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck01 deck =new Deck01();

        System.out.println(deck.getSize());
        System.out.println(deck.isEmpty());
        deck.add("Clovers","Jack",11);
        deck.add("Diamonds","King",13);
        deck.add("Hearts","Queen",12);
        deck.add("Spades","9",9);
        deck.add("Clovers","7",7);
        deck.add("Diamonds","Ace",1);
        deck.add("Hearts","Jack",11);
        deck.add("Spades","Ace",1);
        deck.add("Clovers","3",3);
        deck.add("Diamonds","5",5);

        deck.display();
        System.out.println(deck.isEmpty());
        System.out.println(deck.getSize());

        deck.remove("Diamonds","5",5);
        deck.remove("Spades","Ace",1);
        deck.display();
        System.out.println(deck.getSize());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I was using a static array, trying to make a "remove" method. I be making a dynamic array later, so I keep this in mind. Thanks.